# What does this error mean: "System.FormatException has been thrown, unknown Char"?

Tags: c#, loops

I'm a C# beginner, and I've written a basic looping calculator here (code below). When I 'Exit' the program as definined as a loop break, I get the following error on Line 31: "System.FormatException has been thrown Unknown char". Can someone please explain what this means and how I might edit my code to avoid such an error? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Greeting.

            Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to calculator.");
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter 'Exit' to stop.");

            // Persistent loop with an exit option.

            while (true)
            {

            // Get three input values from user, separated by spaces.

            Console.Write ("Input two values with an operation, with spaces between.");

            // Get values from user.

            string text = Console.ReadLine ();
            string[] parts = text.Split (' ');
            float value1 = Convert.ToSingle (parts [0]);
            string operation = parts [1];
            float value2 = Convert.ToSingle (parts [2]);

            // Loop exit option.

            if(text == "exit" || text == "Exit")
                break;

            // Establish the variable to store the result,
            // initialized to zero, to be updated by the computation.

            float result = 0;

            // Switch between operations depending on the symbol input.

                switch (operation) 
                {
                    case "+":
                        result = value1 + value2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = value1 - value2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = value1 * value2;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = value1 / value2;
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        result = value1 % value2;
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = (float)Math.Pow (value1, value2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine ("ERROR");
                        break;
                }

                // Print out the result.

                Console.WriteLine (value1 + " " + operation + " " + value2 + " = " + result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you start with var input = Console.ReadLine(), and then check the result of input for either "exit" or an expression for your calculator. You initial prompt should be "Input two values with an operation, with spaces between, or type 'exit' to exit."

Comment: That means you should ask for `exit` at the end of the while loop, instead of at the beginning.

Comment: Simple solution -- makes sense, thank you!

Comment: If you have another question, you should post again. It isn't fair to change your question and un-accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
...
Console.WriteLine ("Welcome to calculator.");
Console.WriteLine ("Enter 'Exit' to stop.");

while(true) {
    Console.Write ("Input two values with an operation, with spaces between.");
    string text = Console.ReadLine ();
    if(text == "exit" || text == "Exit")
        break;
    string[] parts = text.Split (' ');
    ...
```

Comment: I believe it would be more appropriate if the line Enter 'Exit' to stop is added at the end of "Input two values with an operation, with spaces between." In this way, the user will know after every calculation what they have to do to exit.

Comment: Thanks M. Raees, this makes sense! I suspected I just needed to reorder my operations a bit without having to do anything radically new.

Comment: I simply changed the if statement to refer to 'text' and not a new variable ('exit') which was defined unnecessarily -- so that works. But here's a follow-up question, when exiting the program, I get a "System.FormatException has been thrown unknown char" error. What is that about? I'm going to update my question to address that.